# Нужны нормальные спойлеры

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, редактор, markdown

Нужны нормальные сворачиваемые спойлеры.

> Имеющиеся
>  занимают
>  отведённое
>  по вертикали
>  место,
>  что
>  неудобно.

Примеры:

- [Надо поместить под спойлеры результаты замены](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498787/178988)
- [В качестве спойлера использован сниппет](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476703/178988)
- [Надо поместить под спойлеры результаты выполнения команд](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502102/178988)
- [Надо поместить в спойлер полный вывод команды](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803305/178988)

---

Ещё одно использование. Теперь баги на мете принято описывать [на двух языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4114/178988). Кажется весьма логичным загнать английскую версию под спойлер, поскольку она не интересна никому кроме разработчиков.

Comment: Дубликат же http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/406/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: @Nofate, там упоминался спойлер - да. Но ведь не дубликат, потому что там предлагается полностью переделать редактор и пачка новых фич, а я прошу только спойлер и привожу конкретные примеры, где он нужен. К тому же, там уже есть статусный тег, поэтому в той теме шевелиться несколько бесполезно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а это не повлияет на поиск (вопросов ответов) если часть информации будет скрыта? Многие "умники" побегут редактировать старые вопросы и прятать все что нужно и нет, а ведь есть вопросы с громоздким описанием, но оно нужно! Если спрятано, значит немаловажно или вовсе не важно! Меня лично даже скрытый код раздражает.

Comment: @HamSter, на поиск через поиск или Ctrl+F на странице? Не знаю, но думаю, что первое вполне реализуемо при желании.

Comment: @Qwertiy, на любой поиск через поисковик или прямо тут на сайте.

Comment: @HamSter, этот вопрос даже сейчас по тексту имеющегося спойлера не ищется [поиском на сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178988+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8) и [гуглом](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8+site%3Aru.meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: на мобильный версии спойлер очень короткий https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTofL.jpg

Comment: @Danis, ну значит для мобильной, возможно, не нужны. А обратно свернуть после разворачивания можно?

Comment: нет не получается

Comment: @Danis, значит тоже нужны нормальные)

Comment: Это, кстати, не все проблемы спойлера. Он не предлагает обратно свернутся, когда открыли.

Comment: @AnastasiaVovremya, не уверен, но возможно, раньше умел скрываться по повторному клику.

Answer (score 12):

[Главный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) уже [сказал, что не сделает](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199), т.к. не хочет поощрять постинг без разбору огромных портянок. Если что-то хочется спрятать, то, скорее всего, оно в ответе и не нужно.

Comment: Но ведь для сниппетов эта возможность есть и при желании можно прятать в сниппет. Хотя это и не очень удобно.

Comment: По ссылке очень хорошо видно как сайт управляется сообществом.

Comment: Интересно, а что мне мешает нафигачить портянку в сниппет? И не раз? Там портянка поощряется, получается? А так — нет. Бред же ж.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, сниппет это все же минимальный пример, просто для фронтенда. Портянки и там не поощряются.

Comment: @Nofate ну вот допустим я в ответе привожу примеры использования или best-practice... в сниппет входят css html и js .... 4 примера растянутся далекоооооо. А под спойлерами  четверть странички...... Получается не поощряется давать правильные развернутые адекватные, направленные дать понять почему так а не иначе, ответы. А, действительно, направлено всё на Copy and Pasting from stack overflow

Comment: *А, действительно, направлено всё на Copy and Pasting from stack overflow*  - ну это само собой )

Answer (score 1):

Как известно, сейчас скрыть код можно только в сниппет, но если код имеет невыполнимый характер посредством браузера, скрыть его не получится или он будет невыполним.

В ответ может поступать код не только одного языка, а сразу нескольких, поэтому необходимо упаковать небольшой код в спойлер, который не будет растягивать ответ на пол страницы.

[image: показать код]

[image: скрыть код]

Неплохо было бы иметь возможность давать название сниппету

[image: script.js]

Answer (score 1):

Ещё есть проблема с памятью мобильного устройства, когда ответов много и в них всякие там картинки.

Это я к тому что спойлера не хватает как раз для сокрытия объемных ресурсов, с предотвращением их преждевременной загрузки соответственно

Comment: Не согласен, что картинки надо скрывать. Наоборот всегда это бесит на сайтах...

Comment: @Qwertiy я не говорю что все, автор должен решать