# как сделать свертку кода?

Tags: обсуждение

1. Как делается еффект при публикации ответа, что если много кода, более 20-30 строк, то создаётся "div" и в нём можно листать код отдельной "собственной" прокруткой, а отображается часть.
2. Возможно в будущем это появится в инструментах?

Найти быстро ответы с этой функцией не получается, но думаю все видели.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2666/178988

Comment: Не ожидал что это называется спойлер.

Comment: Мне показалось, что в отдельных вопросах код, который помечается `{}`  в редакторе, имеет меньше отображаемых строк чем обычно, к тому же кажется была кнопка "скопировать код". Как это делается?