# Визуальный редактор на stackoverflow

Tags: дефект, поддержка, редактор

Неужели нельзя сделать нормальный визуальный редактор?!

Редактор убогий, если к изображению добавить спойлер, то по сути он должен свернуться в линию (МАЛЕНЬКУЮ ПОЛОСКУ), а он применяет на себя размеры изображения (ОГРОМНЫЙ КВАДРАТ)... это ужасно. И все эти теги, будто в dos гамаешь. 2020 год!

ОС Windows - имеет визуализированный интерфейс и это удобно. Linux - неудобно (да, знаю, что он там есть и т.п и то, что причины её не популярности не только в интерфейсе).

Нормальный визуальный редактор на хабре (вот ещё б комьюнити как тут), почему не сделать тут такой же? Авторы стака поклонники Linux, DOS?. Я создал пост и там эти картинки занимают большую часть пространства, решил обернуть их в спойлер и для этого, мне нужно было залезть в доки, посмотреть как этот спойлер поставить (кстати, это делает крайне необычно) и только потом мне получилось это сделать, но надо же, это чудо каким-то образом порезало мне код, что часть его было за его пределами...

Люди заходят в пост и видят вот это полотно из картинок.. я только отпугиваю людей, которым просто лень всё это читать. хотя, там мало всего, но визуально - много.

Можно же запилить норм визуальный редактор и оставить этот хард-консоль-редактор для тех, кто не может без него.

мне нравится Linux и я её люблю, но пользуюсь Windows. удобство я люблю больше. Или лень.. кому как удобно это понимать)

Comment: Наверное вы как-то странно любите linux, если в windows вам комфортней / А с мыслями о редакторе в SO я согласен

Comment: Советую отделить претензии по спойлеру от основного невнятного холивара на тему визуального редактора и Windows/Linux. За второе закидают минусами, а вот то, что спойлер не сворачивает содержимое, действительно плохо. И к редактору это особо не относится, после публикации в самом сообщении он также не сворачивается.

Comment: @avp чего тут странного? свою жену Вы можете любить за её красивые глаза, а любовницу за красивые ноги. (это пример. о Вас я ничего не знаю и знать не хочу.).

Comment: @dJoni.D ну... стереотипы: либо человек линуксоид и ненавидит винду, либо наоборот. Хотя конечно это далеко не так IRL бывает. Я пользуюсь Линуксом, но ничего против windows не имею, просто я к ней не привычен и не фанат. ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor а за что не любить ОС Linux? Это почти единственный вариант миграции с windows, единственный способ уйти от этого монополиста (apple в расчёт не берём. я не люблю брёвна). У ней шикарная производительность, масса возможностей для кастоматизации, мощная консоль. политика открытого ПО мне тоже симпатизирует. в win же для меня более удобна. для неё есть всё, что мне нужно. у linux с этим проблемы: если и есть, то с этим нужно возиться, чтобы это работало, или же этого просто нету ну и другие косяки..

p.s. хотелось бы, чтобы у linux были такие же красивые ноги)) я буду ждать^^

Answer (score 2):

Спойлер - это способ спрятать часть текста от случайного прочтения, а не способ экономии места. Насколько я помню, способа сворачивать часть контента не делают намеренно, потому что считается, что лишней информации ни в вопросах, ни в ответах быть не должно. Информация либо необходимая - и тогда её не следует прятать, либо ненужная - и тогда её следует удалить.

Что же касается картинок - решение проблемы занимаемого ими места известно давно, это небольшая превьюшка и ссылка на полную версию. Вот так:

[image: скриншот]

```
[![скриншот][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbIrq.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ8P7.png
```

Comment: Hint: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ8P7s.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ8P7b.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ8P7m.png

Comment: способность спойлеров прятать текст для экономии места - пусть и не гласно, но используется, чтобы не делать простыни. прятать объёмы текста и большие картинки для удобства восприятия остального содержимого. я считаю, что пользоваться разметкой неудобно. это как пилить сайты таблицами.есть же нормальные решения.. у таблиц тоже есть свои плюсы, однако их уже почти никто не использует для этого.

Comment: к тому же, если я тут рассказываю о сюжете в какой-нибудь драме, то я бы тогда лучше скрытый текст использовал. а спойлер, чтобы сэкономит место - убрать вид полотна, сделать "удобно" для читателя.

Comment: @dJoni.D спойлер - это и есть скрытый текст

Comment: @PavelMayorov есть тег такой [hide] который скрывает текст и принимает размеры текста или то, что скрыто там. только тут я вижу спойлер в таком виде. на других сайтах это тонкая горизонтальная линия. быть может только на стаке знают, каким должен быть правильный спойлер...

Comment: @dJoni.D я видел на других сайтах оба варианта

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну и я видл) только факта дефектности тутошнего спойлера это всё не меняет да и разметки этой. конечно можно привыкнуть к этому, ко многому можно и потом особо этого не замечать (конечно в этом я сомневаюсь) но можно сделать норм редактор и оставить эту разметку. пользователь уже сам решит на своё усмотрение, что ему ближе.

Answer (score 2):

1. Редактор скоро будет :(
2. Ненавижу wysiwyg-редакторы. Нормально форматировать в них что-либо нереально и жутко бесит. Единственная полезная фича - таблицы.
3. [Нужны нормальные спойлеры](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2666/178988).

Comment: Вот правильно! Но я думаю там можно будет старый добрый markdown включить, а всю эту wysiwyg фигню выключить (так в Teams например).

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, выключить можно, но превью уберут. По идее вместо этого выключение и включение markdown'а, но кажется разметка до сих пор меняется при этом :(

Comment: Да? Вот блин... Ниче напишем расширение.

Answer (score 0):

У WYSIWYG редакторов есть свои проблемы. Эта опция есть в Teams например. Но там я ее для себя отключил — это неудобно. Когда ты оформляешь вопрос в MD, то это как кодинг — ты пишешь код, который даст тебе нужный результат. Когда же ты оформляешь WYSIWYG, ты не видишь разметки и это неудобно (ну по крайней мере лично мне).

Почему вы думаете, что у линукс не "визуальный интерфейс" я не знаю. В линуксе можно поставить DE (а в большинстве дистров он и так есть), а терминал — это контроль на системой и очень удобное средство, которое делает ровно то, что ты сказал. А про поклонников DOS вообще не понятно — причем тут они ??? (и линукс тоже тут не причем...). Это такая попытка спровоцировать сообщество ?

@MSDN.White.Knight:

> Советую отделить претензии по спойлеру от основного невнятного
> холивара на тему визуального редактора и Windows/Linux. За второе
> закидают минусами, а вот то, что спойлер не сворачивает содержимое,
> действительно плохо. И к редактору это особо не относится, после
> публикации в самом сообщении он также не сворачивается.

Да, это похоже на троллинг. У нас *запрещенны* всякиe холивары и т.д.

Спойлеры редко используются здесь, да, могут быть баги. Но их надо репортить без всякого "наезда". Да и вообще к редатору на StackOverflow надо немного привыкнуть, может вы сами чего не так сделали. И много картинок в вопросе/ответе — не надо, по большей части оформляйте все текстом, с ним удобней работать.

Ну в общем не ясно, что вы хотите. Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, пока вы его не конкретизируете.

Теперь по поводу того конкретного вопроса "в котором очень много картинок" (кстати можно было сюда и ссылку добавить). Вот [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1192724/revisions), которая его немного улучшит. Картинок там вовсе не много, а сколько надо, и это очень хороший вопрос — и по оформлению и по содержанию.

Comment: да потому, что я в порыве ярости потерял суть того, что писал. 

```ОС Windows - имеет визуализированный интерфейс и это удобно. Linux - неудобно (да, знаю, что он там есть и т.п и то, что причины её не популярности не только в интерфейсе).```

в скобках там я написал, что он(визуальный интерфейс) тоже там есть. в общем, я имел ввиду недружелюбность linux'a к пользователям в целом, если сравнивать её и windows, то выигрывает она. Вы ж сами наверняка сидите на win))

Comment: Для понимания вопроса нужны были картинки. Это зачастую лучше, чем написать текст. особенно в случае дизайна. (почему я так думаю, да потому что меня часто просили показывать картинками.

то что редактор так проблемно реагирует на них и на что-то ещё, то это проблема редактора. я же говорю, на хабре есть редактор - прелесть. всё аккуратно, нет этих пояснений, этих блоков под редактором, багов там тоже нету)

Comment: и да, я не наезжал - это был крик новичка, который вот сходу утонул в этом всём.. блоках с пояснениями, кривом спойлере и кривой вставке кода. в этом неудобстве. сейчас всё делают удобным.

по поводу вопроса: ссылка нужна на сайт с проблемой?

p.s. а причём тут поклонники? я сравнил удобство DOS с той же windows в плане интерфейса. в dos нужно всё буквами писать, а не кликать мышкой по кнопками... или же cделать dos интерфейс для windows 10, это будет удобно?

и вот эти ограничения в комметах аля твиттер)))..

Comment: @dJoni.D "`Вы ж сами наверняка сидите на win)`"— неправда. Я не люблю win. Я в основном использую Linux (например Ubuntu). (Еще был длительный опыт с маком, но это другое дело...)

Comment: @dJoni.D `я сравнил удобство DOS с той же windows в плане интерфейса. в dos нужно всё буквами писать, а не кликать мышкой по кнопками... или же cделать dos интерфейс для windows 10, это будет удобно? и вот эти ограничения в комметах аля твиттер)))..` — ясное дело, что чистый комманд лайн никто сейчас практически не юзает. Но комбинации cli и gui — вот это лучше всего на мой взгляд.

Comment: @dJoni.D `и да, я не наезжал` — ну, хорошо. Просто к новичкам иногда относятся с подозрением, но тут понятно ;)

Comment: согласен. лучше. но вот тут я вижу cli, а gui в тех пару кнопка в редакторе. всё. я тоже смотрю в сторону linux, но жаль, что так мало всего для неё. мне точно придётся обращаться к win. поэтому отказаться от неё не выходит. монополисты владеют мной)))

Comment: @dJoni.D Да всего хватает, разве что драйверов немного мало. Кстати тока win проги можно на wine запускать.