# Можно ли в ответах на вопросы скрывать код?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, ответы, редактор, форматирование

В справке ответа не нашел. Есть ли на сайте возможность в ответах "скрывать" свой код? Ну для тех случаев, когда участники сообщества задают вопросы с меткой "алгоритм" или, например, метки нет, но из текста вопроса явно видно, что у них проблемы с составлением алгоритма. Вот, на мой взгляд, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201693/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A1-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2/1202098#1202098) такого вопроса. Я бы хотел в ответе опубликовать код, но чтобы он был изначально скрыт и стал доступен только по нажатию на кнопку "посмотреть код" наподобие того, как это реализовано с кнопкой "Выполнить код" в сниппетах `html, css, js`. Есть ли на сайте такая возможность? Если есть, то как ей воспользоваться? Если нет, то я бы предложил реализовать такой функционал.

Comment: Тут в соседнем вопросе [говорят](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2667), что спойлеры не нужны :(

Comment: @andreymal мне кажется, данная возможность  хотя и немного, но ограничила любителей готовых решений. Давайте проголосуем за возможность скрывать код, и может ее реализуют.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужны нормальные спойлеры](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2666/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Вопрос действительно похож, но не дубликат. Там предлагается ввести механику спойлеров, я же спрашивал введена ли она и если да, то как ей воспользоваться.